# Regular Expression change text between tags

Tags: regex, replace, html-content-extraction

I have some code in the following layout,i m using textcrawler to do a find and replace

```
<a>
Name=LineA
epsium
ask
answer
line=10
color=red
</a>

<a>
Name=LineB
Color=Blue
</a>
```

...

Now the question is what regular expression i need to use so as to remove the second block of code between `<a> and </a>`

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what you've tried?

Comment: i tried <a>(.*)</a> but it selects whole thing

Comment: Why is the second block of code more important than the first? `<a>.*?</a>` gets the first block. And you don't need parenthesis.

Comment: I want to replace the second blaock with some thing else so i thought i need to capture using a paranthesis

Comment: Oh, then something like this: `<a>(\s*Name=LineB.*?)</a>` or `<a>(\s*Name=LineB[\S\s]*?)</a>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a>(\s*?Name\=LineB[\S\s]*?)</a>
```

It captures all text between and including the `<a></a>` tags that starts with the text `Name=LineB`.

Comment: I think you are going in right direction except i cannot match/hard code the number of characters ,i m thinking to capture the name LineB in between tags

Comment: Then @sln is right: `<a>(\s*Name\=LineB.*?)</a>` should match the second block.

Comment: Tried,Still cannot get hold of the block :(

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, I'll do :

```
$str =~ s~^(.*?<a>.*?</a>.*?)<a>.*?</a>(.*)$~${1}New text$2~s;
```

the first group contains everything before the second block `<a></a>` and the second group everything after.

In php:

```
$str = preg_replace('~^(.*?<a>.*?</a>.*?)<a>.*?</a>(.*)$~', "${1}New text$2", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks and Thats all great but i m not sure if the  "TextCrawler" uses Perl or php

Comment: @ThinkingCap: I don't know TextCrawler but have a try with the regex in the search and `${1}New text$2` in the replace field.

Comment: +1 Or `s~^(.*?<a>.*?</a>.*?<a>).*?(</a>.*)$~${1}New a body text$2~s` if just replacing the text between.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/<body>([\s\S]*.*)<\/body>/",$replace,$origional);
```

this will replace whole content between body tags.